# A function that uses a regex to parse date and time and returns a datetime object

Tags: python, strings, datetime, regex

The code works, but I think can be simplified, I don't know which specific steps, but my version seems to me quite complicated

I build a function that takes a specific string format and returns a `datetime.datetime` object.

This is the string format `"Fri Oct 11 15:09:30 GMT+01:00 2019"` that I want to convert into a `datetime` object with this format `'%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y'`

(My final goal not in the scope of this question is to convert these strings from a set to calculate the delta time across the samples)

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

def date_extractor(date_string: str) -> str:

 #find the day
 re_day = re.findall(r'\s(\d{2})\s',date_string)

  
  #find the time
  re_hour = re.findall(r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}',date_string)

  #find the month 
  re_month = re.findall(r'\s([a-zA-Z]{3})\s',date_string)
  #find the year
  re_year = re.findall(r'\d{4}',date_string)
  #join with the hour
  join_hour = "".join(re_hour)
  join_day_month_year = "/".join(re_day+re_month+re_year)
  
  combining_string = join_hour +" "+ join_day_month_year
  #Convert to datetime first
  date_obj = datetime.strptime(combining_string, "%H:%M:%S %d/%b/%Y")
  #Convert to string to get the right format
  date_transformed = date_obj.strftime('%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y')
  #Convert again to datetime
  date_transformed = datetime.strptime(date_transformed, '%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y')
  
  #return the final object
  return date_transformed


#testing section
base_string = "Fri Oct 11 15:09:30 GMT+01:00 2019"
converted_string = date_extractor(base_string)
print(f"The converted_string is {converted_string} and it's datatype is {type(converted_string)}" )
```

Comment: Micro-review: "it's" should be "its" in the final line.

Comment: @TobySpeight lol I was sure my code was correct :D Thank you :D

Comment: @AndreaCiufo your code doesn't even output what you said it should: you described yourself as wanting `15:09:30 11/10/2019` but it outputs `2019-10-11 15:09:30`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow, that's a lot of regexes!

> "Fri Oct 11 15:09:30 GMT+01:00 2019" ... convert into a datetime object with this format: "%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y"

Perfect.
You practically gave the concise solution right there.
But then you wandered off into a regex for this field
and a regex for that field.

Let's just use the
[standard](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) `.strptime()`:

```
import datetime as dt

stamp = "Fri Oct 11 15:09:30 GMT+01:00 2019"
fmt = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z%z %Y"
print(dt.datetime.strptime(stamp, fmt))
```

---

Once you have a pair of `datetime` objects,
you can simply subtract them to obtain a `timedelta` object.
And you can interrogate *that* for `.total_seconds()`.

---

Here is some actual code review.

```
  re_hour = re.findall(r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}',date_string)
```

Please name this `re_hms` instead, as it clearly
has more than just the hour.

Also, the `.findall()` probably isn't
the method to prefer, here, given the later need for
a clumsy `"".join(re_hour)` expression.

Answer (score 7):

[J_H's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283199/192133) is good, but I want to give a deeper explanation.

Based on this line from your question, I think you are misunderstanding how datetime objects work:

> I want to convert into a `datetime` object with this forma[t:] `'%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y'`

That doesn't make sense. A datetime object does not store its data in any specific string format. It has separate internal fields that store values for year, month, day, hour, etc. When you create a new datetime object, you are extracting those separate values from the input string, based on the set of instructions provided by the format string.

Looking at this part of your code:

```
  #Convert to datetime first
  date_obj = datetime.strptime(combining_string, "%H:%M:%S %d/%b/%Y")
  #Convert to string to get the right format
  date_transformed = date_obj.strftime('%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y')
  #Convert again to datetime
  date_transformed = datetime.strptime(date_transformed, '%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y')
```

There is no reason to convert your string into a datetime object, then into a different string, then into a *second* datetime object. **The second object is the same as the first object.** It does not matter whether you write the month as `Oct` and extract it with the `%b` instruction, or write the month as `10` and extract it with the `%m` instruction. Both objects know, in the end, that they have been set to the tenth month of the year.

---

The type hinting for your function suggests that you are actually trying to convert your input `"Fri Oct 11 15:09:30 GMT+01:00 2019"` into a *string* with format `'%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y'`. You are not doing that now; your function returns a datetime object rather than a string.

If you actually wanted to do that, you would first turn the string into a datetime object using `.strptime()`, and then you would ask that object to generate a string in your desired format using `.strftime()`.

```
from datetime import datetime

def date_reformatter(date_str: str) -> str:
    expected_input_format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z%z %Y"
    datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, expected_input_format)
    reformatted_date_str = datetime_obj.strftime('%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y')
    return reformatted_date_str
```

If you really do want the datetime object, it is even simpler:

```
from datetime import datetime

def date_extractor(date_str: str) -> datetime:
    expected_input_format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z%z %Y"
    datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, expected_input_format)
    return datetime_obj
```

Comment: And @J_H I really appreciated both answers. Yes, I was not fully aware of how the `datetime` object worked. I read both carefully. This community is amazing and I am very grateful for the time you spend explaining me the theory behind.

Answer (score 5):

Obviously you should use `datetime.datetime.strptime`, but I'll review your original code according to the plan you had to use regexes.

## Correctness

Because you used only 1-space indentation on lines 6 and 7, but 2-space indentation on the rest of the function body (lines 10 onwards), the code doesn't run as-is.

I guess there was a copy/paste error and you are using 2 spaces on lines 6 and 7 too, but unless you have an inviolable reason to keep using 2 spaces, please use 4 spaces for indentation according to PEP 8 (the language official style guide) and the Google Python Style Guide among almost all others.

You described your goal to be:

> I want to convert into a `datetime` object with this forma `'%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y'`

But your code produces this output:

> ```
> The converted_string is 2019-10-11 15:09:30 and it's datatype is <class 'datetime.datetime'>
> ```

That's `2019-10-11 15:09:30` instead of `15:09:30 11/10/2019` which is what you wrote that you wanted.

By the way, `datetime` objects do not have formats. They just store the date and time information in a set of fields. It is only when you turn a `datetime` into a string that you can choose how to format it.

## Whitespace

Also according to the most accepted styles, commas should have a space after them, so all the lines like

```py
re_day = re.findall(r'\s(\d{2})\s',date_string)
```

Should instead be

```py
re_day = re.findall(r'\s(\d{2})\s', date_string)
```

In most cases, operators should also have spaces on both sides, so

```py
join_day_month_year = "/".join(re_day+re_month+re_year)
```

should be

```py
join_day_month_year = "/".join(re_day + re_month + re_year)
```

## Type-hinting and naming

Your typehint is

```py
def date_extractor(date_string: str) -> str:
```

the `-> str` at the end means that `date_extractor` returns a string. But your code currently actually returns a `datetime` object. You have to decide whether you want to:

1. input a date string in one format and output a string that represents the same date in another format, e.g. convert `%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z%z %Y` to `%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y`, in which case a better name would be something like `reformat`.
2. or input a date string in the `%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z%z %Y` format and output a `datetime` object that stores all the date and time data, in which case the type hint should be `-> datetime` instead of `-> str`.

I will assume you wanted to do the second one of these.

## Use doctest!

```py
#testing section
base_string = "Fri Oct 11 15:09:30 GMT+01:00 2019"
converted_string = date_extractor(base_string)
print(f"The converted_string is {converted_string} and it's datatype is {type(converted_string)}" )
```

Because there's not many tests at all in your "testing section", it looks more like example usage, you can convert it into a doctest on your function:

```py
def date_extractor(date_string: str) -> datetime:
   r'''Parse a [resource] date string into a datetime object.
   
   >>> date_extractor("Fri Oct 11 15:09:30 GMT+01:00 2019")
   datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 11, 15, 9, 30)
   '''
   #find the day
   re_day = re.findall(r'\s(\d{2})\s',date_string)
```

Now run `python -m doctest your_code.py` to test that all the `>>>` lines in your docstrings have the expected outputs.

## regexes for parsing

Your regexes are all great and accurate, the way you combine them afterwards is good too.

It's not robust to scan the string for patterns like `r'\s(\d{2})\s'` though, because if someone messed up with the input string and passed in `Fri Oct 11 15:09:30 GMT+01:00 20 19` for example, you would find *two* days and then your function would start doing whacky things.

Instead I'd recommend building one regex that describes the *entire* string. You can use [named capture groups](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups) to extract the relevant parts afterwards. E.g.

```py
>>> match = re.fullmatch(r'(?P<number>\d+) (?P<name>\S+)', '206 David')
>>> match.group('number')
'206'
>>> match.group('name')
'David'
>>> match.groupdict()
{'number': '206', 'name': 'David'}
```

So why not build a big regex describing your expected input format:

```py
re_input = r'(?P<day_name>[a-zA-Z]{3}) (?P<month_name>[a-zA-Z]{3}) (?P<date>\d\d) (?P<hours>\d\d):(?P<minutes>\d\d):(?P<seconds>\d\d) GMT+01:00 (?P<year>\d{4})'
```

Then match on that and catch invalid inputs:

```py
match = re.fullmatch(re_input, date_string)
if match is None:
    raise ValueError('date_string is not in expected format')
```

## Redundant code

I think you did so much back-and-forth conversion between string and datetime at the end of your function to "coerce" the datetime to be in the right format.... but remember datetimes don't have formats. You only need to get it into a `datetime` object one time, what you wrote:

```py
combining_string = join_hour +" "+ join_day_month_year
#Convert to datetime first
date_obj = datetime.strptime(combining_string, "%H:%M:%S %d/%b/%Y")
#Convert to string to get the right format
date_transformed = date_obj.strftime('%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y')
#Convert again to datetime
date_transformed = datetime.strptime(date_transformed, '%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y')
  
#return the final object
return date_transformed
```

and this

```py
combining_string = join_hour + " " + join_day_month_year
date_obj = datetime.strptime(combining_string, "%H:%M:%S %d/%b/%Y")
return date_obj
```

have exactly the same output.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation, It's really valuable the time you spend to analyse all the points of my code. It also describes clearly my weakness as self-taught data scientist, with a basic computer science background and a more statistical knowledge. I will study all the replies I received with the related topics. The value and the knowledge of this community is amazing, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at dateutil.parser.parse - it takes arbitrary date representations and returns a datetime object...i.e.

`import dateutil

for s in "01-Jan-2023 11:33 PM;Monday February 13, 2023 9:00 AM".split(';'):
print(repr(dateutil.parser.parse(s)))

datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 23, 33)
datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 13, 9, 0)
`

You can use datetime.strftime to output a string to you exact specifications.

The dateutil.parser.parse function is very versatile and will parse most string date representations.